# BorderRadius Using HighCharts HeatMap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

Would I be able to round the edges of a heatmap made with highcharts?

See their example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/

I'm trying to get each square to have rounded edges, but the borderRadius command isn't working when I add it.

E.g.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',

        // My addition
        borderRadius: 5,

        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]
```

I have also tried:

```
plotOptions:{
        heatmap:{     
            borderRadius:5
      }
    },
```

Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is no supported, but there is a very easy hack to implement this:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.pointAttrToOptions.r = 'borderRadius';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uds4vvfa/1/